# Trouble coding void* in ffi/luajit

Tags: c, lua, ffi, luajit

I thought I had worked out how to code c pointers in ffi for luajit, such as the following which works as needed:

```
ffi.cdef("void XPLMGetWindowGeometry(XPLMWindowID inWindowID, int * outLeft, int * outTop, int * outRight, int * outBottom)")   DONE
local wLeft = ffi.new("int[1]")
local wRight = ffi.new("int[1]")
local wTop = ffi.new("int[1]")
local wBottom = ffi.new("int[1]")
local winLeft, winTop, winRight, winBottom = 0,0,0,0
XPLM.XPLMGetWindowGeometry(xplm_wnd, wLeft, wTop, wRight, wBottom)
winLeft, winTop, winRight, winBottom = wLeft[0], wTop[0], wRight[0], wBottom[0]
```

However, I am totally stuck with how to define a void* such as the void* inRefcon below, and so far everything I have tried fails.

The code is:

```
ffi.cdef("void * XPLMSetWindowRefCon(XPLMWindowID inWindowID, void * inRefcon)")
-- define pointer in ffi - see below --
XPLM.XPLMSetWindowRefCon(xplm_wnd, cdata)
```

I thought I could just code up an int* and pass that, but obviously not! Tried all of the following variations:

```
local refcon = ffi.new("int[1]")
local refconp = ffi.new("char[1024]", "hello")
local refcon = refconp[0]
local refcon = ffi.typeof("$ *", hello)
local refcon = ffi.typeof("int* [?]")
local refcon = ffi.new("int[1]")
local refcon = ffi.cast("void *", 12)
refcon[0] = 12
local refcon = ffi.new("char [1024]", "foobar")
local refconp = ffi.new("int *")
local refcon = refconp
local refcon = ffi.new("int[10]", 12)
```

I either get an error such as bad argument #2 to 'XPLMSetWindowRefCon' (cannot convert 'int' to 'void *')
or I get a CTD.

What is the trick to declare a void* variable in ffi/luajit?

Ian

Comment: The correct way is `local refcon = ffi.cast("void *", some_pointer)`, but you must use a POINTER instead of a number 12.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by using a pointer, do you mean something like this: --local refconp = ffi.new("void *")
local refcon = ffi.cast("void *", refconp)
Trying to get a grasp of what you mean by pointer, where to get, how to assign. Thx...Ian

Comment: You need to pass pointer to callback function.  Why are you trying to pass number 12 casted to "void*"?  Before trying LuaJIT, you should have clean understanding about how C program should interact with XMLP functions.

Comment: The passing of 12 was a failed attempt at an example I found on Google, obviously didn't work, as most of those examples I posted didn't work. I did come close to the solution though in that I tried the ffi.cast. So now with ffi.cast("void *", some_pointer), my question is how do I define the "some_pointer"? Pointers are a challenge in my case...

Comment: You must write a callback function in C and pass its pointer.  You can't write C function inside LuaJIT.

Comment: So basically if I have a function pointer / callback function (that uses pass by value if I read the ffi info correctly) then I have no way of accessing using luajit and ffi only, I will need to write up some c code too.